# Is CPI related with Clock frequency?

Tags: cpu-architecture

First of all, I apologize for my poor English.

If the computer frequency gets higher, can we get lower CPI(Clock per Instruction)?

I thought CPI is only related to computer structure like pipelining or SMT etc, and the frequency is related to execution time(throughput) not CPI.

But a few days ago I heard a higher frequency helps to get better CPI. I couldn't understand what they told very well but they said memory access time can be reduced when frequency goes higher.

Am I thinking right or is there anything wrong with my think?

Answer (score 2):

That's backwards; for a fixed DRAM access time like 40 nanoseconds (plus some time inside the CPU that scales with frequency), the higher the CPU frequency, the more core clock cycles you have to wait for a cache miss, *hurting* CPI (making it higher).

Of course, usually people talk about IPC these days, because CPUs are superscalar.  IPC = 1/CPI.  Higher IPC = lower CPI = better.  Perhaps you say someone saying lower IPC instead of lower CPI?

---

Separately, to get higher clock speeds, you can make the pipeline longer.  That hurts CPI.  See [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) for some history of "speed demon" processors like the notorious Pentium 4 vs. "brainiac" (high IPC) processors like Skylake or Alpha 21264.

Comment: That is a fantastic guide you linked to. How did you come across that?

Comment: @CodyGray: I forget, probably just found it with Google years ago while I was looking for more info about something, possibly hyperthreading.  I've linked it in quite a few SO answers as background on understanding CPU architecture.

Comment: Well, I wish I had time to read all of your SO answers, rather than reading all the bad ones that get flagged for deletion. :-) Cheers!